# How do I exclude null rows without excluding null cells when pulling Excel into C# using SQL (ADO)?

Tags: c#, sql, excel, null, ado

I have a query like the following:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('MSDASQL', 'Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};DBQ=D:\test.xls','SELECT * FROM Sheet1$]')
```

This brings back rows that are all null if they were ever edited and then deleted. I want to exclude those, but still include rows that have good data but possible null cells.

My first instinct was to do a "WHERE each column IS NOT NULL" ANDed together, like so:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('MSDASQL', 'Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};   DBQ=D:\test.xls', 'SELECT * FROM Sheet1$]')
WHERE 
(
  Col1 IS NOT NULL 
  AND Col2 IS NOT NULL 
  AND Col3 IS NOT NULL 
  AND Col4 IS NOT NULL 
)
```

This effectively eliminates the null rows, but for some reason, also eliminates a row where Col4 had a null entry. I tried this with and without parens around the WHERE clause.

Does anyone see what I might be doing wrong, or in lieu of that, have a suggestion of a different method I can use to achieve the same results?

This is currently being implemented in C# using ADO, but I am testing the query using Sql Server Management Studio 2008.

Comment: Ok...so I realize I can do this in the C# code. I still think this is weird behavior from SQL, so I would like to see answers or thoughts as to why this isn't working as expected in SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
WHERE 
(
  Col1 IS NOT NULL 
  OR Col2 IS NOT NULL 
  OR Col3 IS NOT NULL 
  OR Col4 IS NOT NULL 
)
```

<strike>or</strike>

WHERE Coalesce(Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4) IS NOT NULL (no coalesce function for oledb/excel)

Comment: Because this is OR'd, won't it then exclude a row where only one of the columns is null? That is something I don't want to do.

Comment: No, it will _include_ that row.  Imagine it as if you only had the first part (col1 is not null).  That would only show rows where col1 had a value.  If col1 is null but col2 is not, you would skip that row.  So you need to allow col1 _or_ col2 to be null, just not both.  And so on.